# Undefined error where it shouldn't be Jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]

I get this error when doing this:

```
var request = 'randomcode';
$.post('../php/forms/postrequest.php', 'type=' + request, function (response) {
    var accesscode = response;
});
alert(accesscode);
```

But it seems correct... What's the error?

Comment: try to declare accesscode before post. or use alert in post

Comment: sometime $.post request took more time to success, and next code if depended of $.post body then we would face such condition.

Answer (score 1):

because you declared the variable accesscode inside the post callback method scope.

```
var request = 'randomcode';
$.post('../php/forms/postrequest.php', 'type=' + request, function (response) {
    var accesscode = response;
    alert(accesscode);
});
```

You may define it outside and use the variable outside of your callback method scope to alert. But the value from server may not be available as **ajax is asynchronous** and you may be accessing the variable value even before your ajax code received the response.

```
var request = 'randomcode';
var accesscode ='inital value';
$.post('../php/forms/postrequest.php', 'type=' + request, function (response) {
    var accesscode = response;

});
alert(accesscode);  // will alert('initial value')
```

If you try the above code, you might get the alert `inital value` because your alert line might get executed even before you `$.post` received a response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

sometime $.post request took more time to success, and next code if depended of $.post body then we would face such condition, Do like this

```
var request = 'randomcode';
var accesscode = "";
$.post('../php/forms/postrequest.php', 'type=' + request, function (response) {
    accesscode = response;
});
alert(accesscode);
```

or like this

```
var request = 'randomcode';
$.post('../php/forms/postrequest.php', 'type=' + request, function (response) {
   var accesscode = response;
alert(accesscode);
});
```